# Java Bank Program - How to deduct from the balance

Tags: java, if-statement

i have this simple bank program where you can check your balance, deposit, and withdraw. this is a loop by the way so you can make multiple transactions

```
char anotherTransact, option;
    int balance;
    double deposit, withdraw;
    
    
    do {
    System.out.println("\nWelcome to ABC BANK \n");
    
    System.out.println("B - Check for Balance");
    System.out.println("D - Make Deposit");
    System.out.println("W - Make Withdraw");
    System.out.println("Q - Quit");
    
    
        System.out.print("\nSelect an option : ");
        option = scan.next().charAt(0);
        
        
        balance = 100000; 
        if ((option == 'B') || (option == 'b')) {
            System.out.println("\nYour current balance is " +balance);
        }
        
        else if ((option == 'D') || (option == 'd')) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter amount to Deposit : ");
            deposit = scan.nextDouble();
            if (deposit > 1) {
                System.out.println("Deposit Transaction is successfully completed.");
                double newBalance = 100000 + deposit; 
            }
            else if (deposit > 500000) {
                System.out.println("Deposit Amount must not be greater than 500,000");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Deposit must be greater than zero");
            }
        }
        
        else if ((option == 'W') || (option == 'w')) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter amount to Withdraw : ");
            withdraw = scan.nextDouble();
            if (withdraw % 100 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Transaction is successfully completed.");
                
            }
            else if (withdraw > 150000) {
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount must not be greater then 150,000");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount must be greater than zero");
            }
        }
        
        else {
            System.out.println("\nInvalid entry, enter any valid option : (B/D/W/Q)");
        }
        
        System.out.print("\nWant to Transact another (Y/N?) ");
        anotherTransact = scan.next().charAt(0);        
    }
    
    while ((anotherTransact == 'Y') || (anotherTransact =='y'));
```

the problem is that when i choose the withdraw option, i don't know how it should deduct the balance in the next bank transaction and also to add a deposit in the balance.

like for example, i would deposit  $40 in the bank. then make a new transaction to open my balance that should add up the $40 i deposited. how can i add the deposited money in my balance? and also how to deduct it when i withdraw?

Comment: you are not updating `balance -= withdraw;` and ` balance += deposit;` properly. use switch case for this type of use-case. better use a class and defined method there. and it's wrong to display a success message before doing the transaction. also, a couple of edge cases are missing, you can include thoese as well.

Answer (score 1):

In accounting you don't keep track of any balance value, as it is always calculated dynamically.
A deposit would simply be a positive value (> 0) and a withdrawal a negative value (< 0) in the balance sheet (usually a database table). And if you use data-types alike `int` or `double` ...you could only represent cents; usually `BigDecimal` is being used to represent monetary values.

If you'd like to make this program somehow work, push all transactions into an `ArrayList`. I mean, one hell of a stupid question would be: How do you intent to issue your bank-statements without keeping track of all the transactions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the balance variable. You were setting balance to 100000 every iteration of the loop. Also, I changed it to scan.nextInt() because the balance is an integer. If you want to handle decimals, change balance to double and nextInt back to nextDouble.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    char anotherTransact, option;
    int balance = 100000;
    double deposit, withdraw;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    do {
    System.out.println("\nWelcome to ABC BANK \n");
    
    System.out.println("B - Check for Balance");
    System.out.println("D - Make Deposit");
    System.out.println("W - Make Withdraw");
    System.out.println("Q - Quit");
    
    
        System.out.print("\nSelect an option : ");
        option = scan.next().charAt(0);
        
        
        if ((option == 'B') || (option == 'b')) {
            System.out.println("\nYour current balance is " +balance);
        }
        
        else if ((option == 'D') || (option == 'd')) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter amount to Deposit : ");
            deposit = scan.nextInt();
            if (deposit > 1) {
                System.out.println("Deposit Transaction is successfully completed.");
                balance += deposit; 
            }
            else if (deposit > 500000) {
                System.out.println("Deposit Amount must not be greater than 500,000");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Deposit must be greater than zero");
            }
        }
        
        else if ((option == 'W') || (option == 'w')) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter amount to Withdraw : ");
            withdraw = scan.nextInt();
            if (withdraw % 100 == 0) {
                balance -= withdraw;
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Transaction is successfully completed.");
                
            }
            else if (withdraw > 150000) {
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount must not be greater then 150,000");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount must be greater than zero");
            }
        }
        
        else {
            System.out.println("\nInvalid entry, enter any valid option : (B/D/W/Q)");
        }
        
        System.out.print("\nWant to Transact another (Y/N?) ");
        anotherTransact = scan.next().charAt(0);        
    }
    
    while ((anotherTransact == 'Y') || (anotherTransact =='y')); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: `deposit > 1` should be `deposit > 1 && deposit < 500000`. floating point transaction should also be suppored. `withdraw % 100 == 0` should be `withdraw % 100 == 0 && withdraw  < balance` etc.

Comment: @roottraveller Yea but that's not what OP asked for, I imagine they can figure out exclusion cases themselves once they know how to update the variable. And since this bank only allows withdrawals in hundred dollar bills, I assume they dont accept coin deposits

Answer (score 1):

First of all, deduct from balance is just `balance -= withdrawal` which is the same as `balance = balance - withdraw`, this will update the variable `balance`. When you want to print the currentnt balance, just call this variable. 
*`double newBalance = 100000 + deposit;` won't update your balance, because you are only printing **balance** not **newBalance***
Secondly,  **balance** shouldn't be an int variable.
And some of your transaction rules are not correct. In the withdrawal, you should check if the balance is greater than the withdrawal amount and the withdrawal amount is greater than 0(`balance > withdraw && withdraw > 0`). In addition, `withdraw % 100 == 0` does not really make sense to me, it is not the condition for `"Withdrawal Amount must be greater than zero"`

Comment: the withdraw % 100 == 0 actually means that the withdrawal should be divisible by 100. i don't know if that was the right way to put it

Comment: @Liyanna if you want the withdraw divisible by 100 then that is correct